# How to cancel an auto-send email - can't find the script or source to cancel?

Tags: email, scripting, gmail, google-email-settings-api

Used Google Scripts and when we search my history, the script is gone

I followed [this link](http://help.grow.com/hc/en-us/articles/205130045-How-do-I-schedule-a-recurring-email-through-Gmail-)  to set the email up, and now I cannot cancel it, any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link of the tutorial you provided, it looks like you created the script from inside a spreadsheet. They can be found using menu `Tools => Script Editor`. From there you can delete/edit the function that is sending the email. You might also want to check the document about [Development Environment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/managing_projects), this will discus about creating and deleting projects, linking of libraries and more. Hope this helps.